# AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK not performing click

Tags: android, accessibility

I am trying to perform the click action on a button for another app, but it is not working. Here´s my code:

```
if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED && lgPhone){

    if (info.getContentDescription() != null){
        if (info.getContentDescription().toString().equals("Merge calls")){

            List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> mergeButtonList =
                    info.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.android.incallui:id/mergeButton");
            if (mergeButtonList != null) {
                AccessibilityNodeInfo mergeButton =mergeButtonList.get(0) ;
                if (mergeButton.isClickable()){
                    Log.i("important Information","Is the button clickable?:"+mergeButton.isClickable());
                    mergeButton.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I do get the logs printed and it returns "True" but does not perform the click option. If I access the actions for that specific event I get this:

```
actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: 
ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null,
AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLICK - null, AccessibilityAction: 
ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: 
ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: 
ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: 
ACTION_SET_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null]
```

so I think this is not working because the ACTION_CLICK option is null, but I´m not sure.

Comment: Did you find any solution?